# Strange GIT behaviour in VS2022 - Shows error but still completes action

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, visual-studio-2022

I'm having a strange problem with Git i VS2022 and VS2019.
When I Push, fetch or pulls I get a error saying "failed to fetch from the remote repository. see the output window for more details" - This is the message for fetch but almost the same for the other operations.

The stange part is that the operation is a succes - Git fetches, pulls and pushed fine and I can see the change in the project and on dev.azure.com where my repository is.

The output windows gives nothing despite the error message.

[image: Error message]

I've tried signing out from VS but the problems.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2022-failed-to-fetch-from-the-remote-repository/1541430 suggests 1) It's not a problem, 2) It's a problem with credential management, and 3) that there's a fix for it as of 14 Oct 2021 :) . Are you on the most recent release of VS2022?

Comment: I'm using version 17.0.1 - VS show no updates so it should be the newest.
I'ved tried setting the creadentials helper to GCM core but the error remains

Comment: When I change the credential helper to "GCM for Windows" the error seem to go away - maybe this is because I'm useing creadentials fra windows(logged in on domain/AD )

Comment: As-is, this question is unlikely to have a single answer that would be applicable to all instances where a user would encounter this issue.  Additional information (e.g. verbatim log output, git version, repo configuration, commands being ran, etc) would be helpful for future visitors, so that anyone who may be experiencing the issue can make sure it matches their scenario, and so that any future answers are specific to this exact issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me seem to be setting the credentials helper to GCM for windows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the credential helper didn't fix it for me, but this command did. For example, to fix it for a project in directory {project-directory}:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory {project-directory}
```

Answer (score 0):

I built an app from the .Net 6 Core Angular template. When running the app, the ClientApp/.angular/cache folder contained files too large to push to Github. The .gitignore files doesn’t exclude these files from the repo and seems to cause the issue. Pushing the template before building from works, but I think the folder should also be included in the .gitignore file to ensure successful pushes after builds. Adding /.angular to .gitignore seems to have done the trick for me.